# Python: looping a python script in another python script with parameter passing

Tags: python

I am trying to run a py script in loop from another py file with a parameter passing.

I am trying the following:

```
Script1: 
lst = [12,23,45,67,89]
age_lst = []
for i in lst:
  age_i = os.system("python script_to_run {0}".format(int(i)) )
  age_lst.append(age_i)
```

Below is the code for `script_to_run.py`

```
Script2:script_to_run.py
def age(age:int):
  estimated_val = age+2
  return estimated_val
if __name__=="__main__":
  my_age = int(sys.argv[1])
  final_age = age(age=my_age)
  print(final_age)
```

Whenever I am running Script 1 where I am calling Script 2 (script_to_run.py) It is running fine but `age_lst[]` is being populated only with 2.

Expectation is

```
age_lst = [14,25,47,69,91] <---adding 2 with all elements in age_lst
```

What I am missing?

Also when I am running the `Script1.py` from cmd, I am getting error `python: can't open file 'script_to_run': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system` runs the program and returns its exit code. Your script writes to standard output, a different beast entirely. Exactly what returns from `os.system` is OS dependent. On linux for example, its the `exit` code, limited to 0-255, shifted left with signal information added. Messy.

But since you are converting the output to a string and printing to stdout anyway, just have the parent process read that. The `subprocess` module has several functions that run programs. `run` is the modern way.

```
import subprocess as subp
import sys

lst = [12,23,45,67,89]
age_lst = []
for i in lst:
    proc = subp.run([sys.executable, "script_to_run.py", str(i)],
        stdout=subp.PIPE)
    if proc.returncode == 0:
        print("script returned error")
    else:
        age_lst.append(int(proc.stdout))
print(age_lst)
```

Comment: I am still getting the following 2 errors: `can't open file 'script_to_run': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arghyar559\Desktop\my_folder\Data_Model\Script1.py", line 26, in <module>
    age_lst.append(int(proc.stdout))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b''`

Comment: Oh, right. Its `"script_to_run.py"` ... add the extension. I'll add a return code check also.

Comment: see in my actual code `script_to_run` is `os.path.join(file_path,file_name)` where `file_name` is the actual py file i.e. Script2.py. Do I have to add another `.py` extension

Comment: Oh. so "script_to_run" is a variable name? if You do `[sys.executable, script_to_run, str(i)]` you should be fine. Or `["python", script_to_run, str(i)]`. If you are doing it as a shell command, make sure you get the variable's value `f"python {script_to_run} {i}"` but also add the `shell=True` parameter to the `subp.run` command.

Comment: Thanks!! Figured out this earlier and made the changes accordingly.

Comment: Just another question: what if i remove the `print` from Script2.py?

Comment: You need a way to get the data from the called process to the caller. The print does it by converting the integer to a string and sending that. If your data is more complicated, you'll still need a way to serialize. Lots of options there, like JSON. So you need to write _something_

Comment: Ok. Lets say in that for loop I must have to pass an `int`, so can I replace `str(i)` to `int(i)` within `proc = subp.run([sys.executable, "script_to_run.py", str(i)], stdout=subp.PIPE)`?

Comment: On the command line, things have to be strings, so `str(i)` from the parent and `int(sys.argv[1])` in the child is normal. If you want to pass binary, or something large, the parent could write it to the child's `stdin` and the child read if from there. Or write a temporary file. The `struct` module can help with binary. The unix philosophy has always preferred passing things as strings as it is generally more flexible.